# How to stop event inside a timeout function on keypress?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> It's been 4 hours and I am still struggling with multiple alerts after
>   using a timeout. The use-case is very simple

1- User input some value inside an input field (with is a number field).

2 - Then once the end-user stop enter the number. I need that text field value for the calculation.

3 - And then based on some of the condition I need to show some alert message.

**Issue** - ***I am getting 2 tice alert after using timeout I don't know why any help would be really appreciated.***

```
$('#0639').on('keydown', 'input', function(e){
  clearTimeout(ty);
  var that = $(this)
  var ty = setTimeout(function(){
    if(that) {
      console.log(that.val()) // This is work inside timeout only
      alert('true'); //This should alway be once but it's keep showing.
      //This is not working inside the timeout. 
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
  },1000);
})
```

Comment: Move the variable declaration `ty` above event regestration.

Comment: @MadhuMagar can you please explain a bit more ?

Comment: Can you explain why you use settimeout function?

Comment: @JuChengJiang Forgetting the value of text field value I tried `keypress` as well but that also not working for ex: if I input `11` I will get `1`

Comment: @AnilYadav your clearTimeout(ty) is not working because in every keydown event `ty` may have different number (which is id) or null.

Comment: Thanks @MadhuMagar  my bad

Comment: @AnilYadav You do not need setimeout function and I updated it. Please try to use it..

Comment: @JuChengJiang without setTimeout I am not able to get full entered value.

Comment: My concern would be the attempted usage of `stopImmediatePropagation` within a timeout.  There's no guarentee that the event will not have already propagated within a 1 second time interval.  In fact, if it had not propagated by that time span, I would have serious performance concerns about the logic.

Comment: The timeout was working fine I just wanted to stop the further event inside that timeout which is possible via clear the timeout but I used that in wrong way.

Comment: @Taplar I think I will remove that `stopImmediatePropagation`  because that I used to show I tried that as well and I guess that is also not making any difference.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var ty; 
$('#0639').on('keydown', 'input', function(e){
  if (ty) {
   clearTimeout(ty);
  }
  var that = $(this)
  ty = setTimeout(function(){
    if(that) {
      alert('true');
      console.log($(this).val()) // This is work inside timeout only
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
  },1000);
})
```